# Edit texts in a PDF on Chrome using Chrome inspect

Tags: pdf, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

Is there any way to modify texts in PDF on Chrome using the Chrome inspect tool? I was stuck because in the Chrome inspect element, differently than any other websites and even PowerPoint presentations opened in Chrome, I'm able to modify texts, while with PDFs I cannot. Does anyone know how to do it?
Edit: Yes I know that the changes made through Chrome DevTools are temporary, but usually I'm able to make those changes, even if they're temporary. But with PDFs I can't.

Comment: No, the changes you make in devtools won't be saved in PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Found this question because I was googling a similar situation--I was wanting to manipulate type sizes and margins on a PDF in inspector via Chrome. I found that FireFox DevTools will allow you to view those styles and even alter the content in the PDF while in browser. I am late to the game but hope this provides answers for someone else in the future.

Comment: Hi what is the name of the add on for Firefox/Chrome exactly? I'm unable to find something called DevTools. Does it allow us to edit content and then download the edited Pdf?

Comment: I can inspect and edit the values in Firefox's dev tools but those changes are not reflected in the actual rendered document at all.

Answer (score 0):

There are differences in the way some browsers handle PDF data.

Chromium based browsers are more traditional in that the PDF plug-in is based on a Foxit/Skia collaboration, So you need to understand in that case, the downloaded PDF you are viewing is in the binary application/pdf (file already outside of the html wrapper). Note this was the plug-in for Edge Version II but see below.

Just as you cannot edit the PDF text in Acrobat Reader, the most you can do is incrementally add comments/annotation or field data to the end of the file, before save as a secondary download. The server cannot see your changes unless you submit as an upload.

With Firefox and Google docs there is often a different approach where the PDF is "Repr"oduced as an "Ex"ample (A ReprEx of the PDF) so it is built of a hybrid image and text overlay to emulate that part of the real PDF source. When you previously or later save the underlying downloaded PDF (for viewing) it would not necessarily include any browser based HTML editing, in the saving.

There are other techniques for other cases, but to answer the basic OP question most simply, the answer is NO you cannot change a PDF body, only add notes, etc via extensions. Microsoft variant of Chrome I.E. Edge has some inbuilt annotation ability thus does not need a second extension. It is now in version III+ "Powered by Adobe Acrobat". (With hints of more features to come?)

[image]

Like many PDF Readers you can edit the PDF by any external methods, including from command line and the client browser preview will show those changes real time on refresh, since the changes belong to the client owners device.

[image]
[image]

Thus the simplest way to edit a PDF in Chrome (or Edge etc) PDF Viewers is use the Acrobat variant where for a fee you can do everything a client browser window allows.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck doing a basic edit using, I can edit it by converting to .doc or .docx, but some PDF's are formatted in different way so there are so many compatibly issues to deal with and sometimes  the word document would jumble all over, but the simple trick you can use is to convert the PDF to HTML (there are tool available online for free like the other conversions) and then you can open the HTML file in chrome and you can use inspect and make changes and after you are done Ctrl+S and save the new HTML document and convert it to PDF, there you have it.